# QAudioOutput buffer underflow

Tags: qt, audio, qt5

Getting a message "Got a buffer underflow!" after each write in this simple program.

Beep.hpp:

```
#pragma once

#include <QTimer>
#include <QAudioOutput>

class Beep: public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Beep();
    virtual ~Beep();

    void onTimer();

private:
    QAudioOutput m_out;
    QIODevice *m_outDev;
    QTimer m_timer;
};
```

Beep.cpp:

```
#include "Beep.hpp"

int ms = 100;

const QAudioFormat defaultAudioFormat = []()
{
    QAudioFormat format;
    format.setSampleRate(8000);
    format.setChannelCount(1);
    format.setSampleSize(16);
    format.setCodec("audio/pcm");
    format.setByteOrder(QAudioFormat::LittleEndian);
    format.setSampleType(QAudioFormat::SignedInt);
    return format;
}();

Beep::Beep() :
        m_out(defaultAudioFormat),
        m_outDev()
{
    m_out.setBufferSize(16 * ms);
    m_outDev = m_out.start();

    QObject::connect(&m_timer, &QTimer::timeout, this, &Beep::onTimer);

    m_timer.setSingleShot(false);
    m_timer.start(ms);
}

Beep::~Beep()
{
}

void Beep::onTimer()
{
    std::vector<uint8_t> samples(16 * ms);
    m_outDev->write((char*) &samples.front(), samples.size());
}
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>

#include "Beep.hpp"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication app(argc, argv);
    Beep beep;
    return app.exec();
}
```

This test program is just writing buffers with zeros. With real data there are cracking sounds.

Writing more data or changing timings makes it worse. What's wrong with this code?

Answer (score 0):

Using a Timer is the wrong way to do it.

Use the notify() signal

```
void AudioManager::init_audio(AudioManager *mgr) {
    if (mgr->stream_id == -1) return;

    mgr->audio_format.setSampleRate(mgr->context->time_base.den);
    mgr->audio_format.setSampleSize(16);
    mgr->audio_format.setChannelCount(2);
    mgr->audio_format.setCodec("audio/pcm");
    mgr->audio_format.setSampleType(QAudioFormat::SignedInt);
    QAudioDeviceInfo info(QAudioDeviceInfo::defaultOutputDevice());
    if (!info.isFormatSupported(mgr->audio_format)) {
        mgr->audio_format = info.nearestFormat(mgr->audio_format);
    }

    mgr->audio_out = new QAudioOutput(mgr->audio_format, nullptr);
    mgr->audio_out->setNotifyInterval(15);
    mgr->audio_out->setBufferSize(mgr->context->time_base.den * 4); // 1 second worth of stereo data

    connect(mgr->audio_out, SIGNAL(notify()), mgr, SLOT(audio_out_notify()));
    connect(mgr->audio_out, SIGNAL(stateChanged(QAudio::State)), mgr, SLOT(audio_out_state_changed(QAudio::State)));
    qreal volume_out = (qreal)parent->volume / 100.0f;
    mgr->audio_out->setVolume(volume_out);
    mgr->audio_out_device = mgr->audio_out->start();
}
```

This will be called when the audio playback requires more data

```
void AudioManager::audio_out_notify() {
    qDebug() << "Audio notify";
    check_audio_playback();
}
```

Most of the below code will be irrelevant but it is also called is audio has stopped playing.

```
void AudioManager::check_audio_playback() {
    if (stream_id == -1) return;

    pthread_mutex_lock(&audio_mutex);

    if (!audio_out->state() == QAudio::State::IdleState) {
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&audio_mutex);
        return;
    }

    if (parent->pts_start_time < 0.0) {
        if (parent->Video.stream_id == -1 && decode_pos > 65) { // start playback
            parent->pts_start_time = buffers[0].frame_time;
            parent->sys_start_time = (double)parent->timer.elapsed() / 1000.0;
            qDebug() << "Audio playback started";
        } else {
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&audio_mutex);
            return;
        }
    }

    if (playback_pos == decode_pos) {
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&audio_mutex);
        return;
    }



    AudioBuffer *buffer = nullptr;
    double current_sys_time = ((double)parent->timer.elapsed() / 1000.0) - parent->sys_start_time;

    bool bounds = false;
    int skipped = 0;

    while (!bounds) {
        if (playback_pos == decode_pos) bounds = true;
        else {
            AudioBuffer *temp_buffer = &buffers[playback_pos];
            double temp_time = temp_buffer->frame_time - parent->pts_start_time;

            if (temp_time < current_sys_time ) {
                if (buffer) {
                    buffer->used = false;
                    skipped++;
                }
                buffer = temp_buffer;
                playback_pos++; playback_pos %= MAX_AUD_BUFFERS;
            } else {
                bounds = true;
            }
        }
    }

    if (skipped > 0) qDebug("Skipped %d audio buffers on playback", skipped);

    if (buffer) {
        audio_out_device->write((const char *)buffer->data, buffer->buffer_size);
        buffer->used = false;
    }

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&audio_mutex);
}
```

The example on the Qt website wasn't that obvious http://qt.apidoc.info/5.1.1/qtmultimedia/audiooutput.html at first but when I put it in to test it wasn't too bad.

Comment: Notify isn't useful in this case. I've got an external timer, so it's the "pull mode" (according to the `audiooutput.html` example).

Answer (score 0):

The reason was that the source of audio data wasn't a "production-quality module" (it's a dummy testing class): the timer was drifting because its real interval was 10ms plus the processing time.

Other observations:

- make `QAudioOutput::setBufferSize()` bigger
- do `QAudioInput::read()` and `QAudioOutput::write()` in chunks with size that matches `QAudioInput::periodSize()` and `QAudioOutput::periodSize()`